# MAUI multiple errors on publishing android

Tags: maui

While following the steps outlined in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli) for publishing MAUI application. I encountered an issue during the publishing process. This is my first time publishing a mobile application, I'm not familiar with the process and don't have any previous experience.

Step:

```
dotnet publish -f net6.0-android -c Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=myapp.keystore -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=myapp -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=mypassword -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=mypassword
```

I got the following error:

```
MSBuild version 17.6.8+c70978d4d for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(35,5): warning NETSDK1202: The workload 'ios' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/maui-support-policy for more information about the support policy. [C:\Users\GameWa
rden\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-ios]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(35,5): warning NETSDK1202: The workload 'maccatalyst' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/maui-support-policy for more information about the support policy. [C:\User
s\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-maccatalyst]
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  ODWEMob -> C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\bin\Release\net6.0-android\ODWEMob.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\linked; MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runti
  me.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm\6.0.20\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --debug --nollvm "--aot=asmwriter,temp-path=obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\aot\armeabi-v7a\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions,profile-only,profile=C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\Resources\Splash\splash.svg,profile=C:\Program
  Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.553\Sdk\maui.aotprofile,profile=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.553\Sdk\maui-blazor.aotprofile,mtriple=armv7-linux-gnueabi,tool-prefix=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\tools\binutils\arm-linux-androideabi-,outfile=obj\Release\net6.0-androi
  d\android-arm\aot\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll.so,ld-name=ld,ld-flags=-s" "obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\linked\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\linked\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll. [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\OD
WEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\linked\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll [C:\Users\GameWa
rden\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : AOTID 0831BB70-19B3-97F6-5B0E-7248B837B0A5 [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Using profile data file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\Resources\Splash\splash.svg' [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Profile file has wrong header: '<?xml vers'. [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]
  [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\linked; MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.
  win-x64.Cross.android-arm\6.0.20\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --debug --nollvm "--aot=asmwriter,temp-path=obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\aot\armeabi-v7a\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe,profile-only,profile=C:\Users\User\Desktop\ODWE Mob\ODWEMob\ODWEMob\Resources\Splash\splash.svg,profile=C:\Program Files\dotnet\p
  acks\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.553\Sdk\maui.aotprofile,profile=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.553\Sdk\maui-blazor.aotprofile,mtriple=armv7-linux-gnueabi,tool-prefix=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\tools\binutils\arm-linux-androideabi-,outfile=obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\
  aot\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll.so,ld-name=ld,ld-flags=-s" "obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm\linked\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"
```

I tried multiple times to clean the code and build it again, I tried to delete manually bin and obj files and rebuild it again.
In development mode, I don't see any errors. The application is running smoothly. Any help to fix the issue is much appreciated, I can't wait to try my first mobile application on my phone. Thank you!

svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="456" height="456" viewBox="0 0 456 456" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <path d="m 105.50037,281.60863 c -2.70293,0 -5.00091,-0.90042 -6.893127,-2.70209 -1.892214,-1.84778 -2.837901,-4.04181 -2.837901,-6.58209 0,-2.58722 0.945687,-4.80389 2.837901,-6.65167 1.892217,-1.84778 4.190197,-2.77167 6.893127,-2.77167 2.74819,0 5.06798,0.92389 6.96019,2.77167 1.93749,1.84778 2.90581,4.06445 2.90581,6.65167 0,2.54028 -0.96832,4.73431 -2.90581,6.58209 -1.89221,1.80167 -4.212,2.70209 -6.96019,2.70209 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
    <path d="M 213.56111,280.08446 H 195.99044 L 149.69953,207.0544 c -1.17121,-1.84778 -2.14037,-3.76515 -2.90581,-5.75126 h -0.40578 c 0.36051,2.12528 0.54076,6.67515 0.54076,13.6496 v 65.13172 h -15.54349 v -99.36009 h 18.71925 l 44.7374,71.29798 c 1.89222,2.95695 3.1087,4.98917 3.64945,6.09751 h 0.26996 c -0.45021,-2.6325 -0.67573,-7.09015 -0.67573,-13.37293 v -64.02256 h 15.47557 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
    <path d="m 289.25134,280.08446 h -54.40052 v -99.36009 h 52.23835 v 13.99669 h -36.15411 v 28.13085 h 33.31621 v 13.9271 h -33.31621 v 29.37835 h 38.31628 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
    <path d="M 366.56466,194.72106 H 338.7222 v 85.3634 h -16.08423 v -85.3634 h -27.77455 v -13.99669 h 71.70124 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you share both your csproj and splash.svg here?

Comment: I included splash.svg.

Comment: and csproj please